# Remote control software that doesn't require the end user's input

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-control

When I worked at a large corporation a long time ago, their IT staff had a remote control solution that did not require the end user to enter a password, give a password, or anything else of that nature.  They basically connected and had full control instantly.  What software offers this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- VNC
- Team Viewer
- DameWare

as an example of remote control software that supports this feature if properly configured.

Answer (score 2):

If you build your own it's easy, even if its not a good idea.  Presumably your "large corporation" deployed a client-server pair that that recognized each other.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the older packages like [VNC / RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/index.html) (supports newer OSes) supports installing a server (makes the machine it's installed on controllable). Newer remote control solutions are mainly targeted at assistance requests and not having to install any software.

Answer (score 1):

We use Dameware.  This  allows the admin to connect using a domain credential and then  view the user desktop as the user sees it.  Does not need anything from the user if configured properly.  Requires a port open on a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Radmin isn't a bad one. You can use domain level authentication on the server. Basically if you are logged into a machine as an IT staff member and all of the clients out on the floor running the server software are configured to allow connections from IT staff only, if you initiate a connection to a user, their screen comes up and you have view or full control capability. You can set a password and username combo as well, but it is by far easier using NT credentials.

The program itself is good as well, it supports multiple monitor machines and is fairly priced. i think around $20 per license.

Answer (score 1):

My old company used LanDesk Manager. They could remote control to any of the networked computers, or offer remote support through a gateway computer that the client connects to

Answer (score 1):

[Remote Utilities](http://www.remoteutilities.com) has the option to save password that makes logging onto remote machine easier. You will hardly find a decent remote control software that doesn't use a password as security measure. Beware of what programs you download and install, especially those that grant remote access to your machines.

Answer (score 1):

[BO2K](http://www.bo2k.com/whatis.html) fits the description perfectly, and, it's free :)
It's designed for remote-control with no end-user input (much like GoToMyPC).
All you need to do is install the server on the machine you want access to, and then you can use the client to access that box.